# JWPlayer 6 prev and next buttons not shown

Tags: jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Following is my code to create a JW Player. Ideally, I should be able to see the prev and next buttons if my playlist contains more than 1 element. But for some reason, I am not able to see the buttons. Am I missing something?

```
      jwplayer(id_wrapper).setup({
            playlist: [{
            sources: [{
                file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-52qL9xLP.mp4',
                height: 270,
            },{
                file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-DZ7jSYgM.mp4',
                height: 720
            }],
            title: "Big Buck Bunny",
            description: "Big Buck Bunny is a short computer animated film by the Blender Institute.",
            image: 'http://d3el35u4qe4frz.cloudfront.net/bkaovAYt-480.jpg'
        },{
            file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-I3ZmuSFT.m4a',
            title: "Sintel (audio)",
            description: "Sintel is a short computer animated film by the Blender Institute."
        },{
            file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/kaUXWqTZ-52qL9xLP.mp4',
            title: "Elephant's Dream",
            description: "Big Buck Bunny is a short computer animated film by the Blender Institute.",
            image: 'http://d3el35u4qe4frz.cloudfront.net/kaUXWqTZ-480.jpg'
        }],
        height : 360, //$(this).height() || '360',
        width : 640, //$(this).width() || '100%',
        listbar: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    size: 77
                }
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only see the previous/next buttons if the playlist (listbar) is not visible.